# Hiding recent files in Unity dashboard

Tags: unity, 13.04

Ubuntu 13.04 (though had the same issue in both 12.04 LTS and 12.10).  Unity desktop (yes I like it, shush).

Anyways, when clicking on the dashboard there is a tab for 'Files and Folders'.  I don't have any files on this computer that isn't porn.  In other words, it displays the images there (as it's supposed to), but I can't have it displaying the porn for obvious reasons.  I have disabled 'recent activity' and even added the folder it's all in to the 'do not record activity in the following folders'.  I'm assuming that works but as I don't actually have *any* other files, it still displays them.

I don't want to have to make it a hidden folder because it's on an external HDD and causes issues when moving from computer to computer (I have other movies on it as well).

TL;DR: Get rid of the 'Files and Folders' tab in the dashboard.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall files and app lenses using following command

`sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-Files`

But uninstalling will loose the functionality completely. You can temporary disable any lenses using `lenstoggler`. Unfortunately it is only available for 12.04 via ppa.

You can download the package and give a try. It should work

https://launchpad.net/~aking1012-com/+archive/lenstoggle/+build/3440954/+files/python-lenstoggler_0.1.1-1_all.deb

[Details of lens toggle](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/lens-toggle-quickly-enable-disable.html)